# Calling Sage from Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, sage

I have some sage code that I'd like to call from Haskell. The following code uses [cpython](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpython-3.3.0) to call a pure python script:

test.py:

```
def pytest():
    return 3.5+2
```

Main.hs:

```hs
import qualified CPython as Py
import qualified CPython.Protocols.Object as Py
import qualified CPython.Types as Py
import qualified CPython.Types.Module as Py
import qualified CPython.System as Py
import qualified CPython.Types.Float as Py
import qualified Data.Text as T
import GHC.IO.Handle.FD
import Data.Maybe

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Py.initialize
  path <- Py.getPath
  Py.setPath $ T.pack $ ".:" ++ T.unpack path -- path to the module to load
  test <- Py.importModule $ T.pack "test"
  uname <- Py.getAttribute test =<< (Py.toUnicode (T.pack "pytest"))
  res <- Py.callArgs uname []
  Py.print res stdout
  res' <- Py.fromFloat =<< fromJust <$> Py.cast res
  print $ (res' + 2.0 :: Double)
```

When I compile Main.hs and run it, I get the expected output:

```
5.5
7.5
```

If I add `from sage import *` to test.py, I get (once I catch the exception) `ImportError("No module named 'sage'",)`. Of course test.py loads fine directly from sage. I expected that replacing the `python` executable with a symlink to the `sage` executable would fix the problem, but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to make cpython work with sage, or any other way to call a sage script from Haskell?

Comment: How is sage installed? What happens if you call `print path`? (just making sure the sage libraries are in the path)

Comment: Why did you think that changing a symlink would fix the issue? Your Haskell call is evidently calling the CPython API directly, so it's not running the python interpreter at all but it *creates* its own interpreter inside the Haskell program using the CPython API.  Unfortunately this probably means that it isn't looking at the system directory you are thinking of. Try to add the path to the `sage` package in the `sys.path`.

Comment: @pdexter Strangely, I get parse errors when I include "print" in the python file, even before trying any sage business.

Comment: @Bakuriu Adding the path to the `sage` executable didn't work (nor would I expect it to), and adding the path to sage's `python` executable (in `SageMath/local/bin`) didn't help either.

Comment: I meant to print it in Haskell. Also you need to add the path to the sage libraries, not the executable.

Comment: @pdexter Where in the `SageMath` directory should I include in the path?

Comment: @Eric Wherever the python libraries are. Probably the root of the sagemath library path.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is "which" Python you are using; Sage uses its own Python, NOT your system Python.  You may want to try making a link from

```
$ pwd; local/bin/python --version
/Users/.../Downloads/sage
Python 2.7.10
$
```

That is the one you will need to be linking to, in principle.  In practice, you may want to read the Sage documentation about more links, or other [blog posts](https://mvngu.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/how-to-use-sage-as-a-python-library/) about running scripts.  But anyway it's only that Python which can use `from sage import *`.

Comment: I'm aware that Sage uses it's own python, that's why I created a symlink. How is your suggestion different than what I tried?

Comment: I didn't know what you did, so I suggested this; note that you say you linked to the *Sage* binary and not the associated *Python* binary (which is definitely different).  Anyway, it turns out that a *lot* of people ask about this without realizing this about Sage and "its" Python, so I thought this would be helpful; unfortunately I can't help beyond this as I don't use Sage called from other programs, let alone from Haskell (of which I've compiled precisely two programs).